# Index Out Of Range Exception In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

When I run the following code, after the ColourAddition(selectedstyle,styleselection.getIndex)="Y" line, I get an error every time and when I run the code without the aforementioned line, the program is a success. Please help me figure it out

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dbcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DR As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim dr1 As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim com As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim com1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim ChkdItm As Integer
    Dim NoOfStyles As Integer
    Dim NoOfColours As Integer
    Dim SelectedStyle As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dbcon.ConnectionString = "Provider= Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= CheckedListBox.accdb"
        dbcon.Open()
        com.CommandText = "Select * from ColourTable"
        com1.CommandText = "Select * from StyleTable"
        com1.Connection = dbcon
        com.Connection = dbcon
        DR = com.ExecuteReader
        dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader
        While dr1.Read
            NoOfStyles += 1
        End While
        While DR.Read
            ColoursClb.Items.Add(DR.GetString(1))
            NoOfColours += 1
        End While
        SelectedStyle = StyleSelection.getIndex
    End Sub
    Public colourAddition(NoOfStyles, NoOfColours) As String

    Private Sub AddColourBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddColourBtn.Click
        If ColoursClb.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ChkdItm In ColoursClb.CheckedIndices
                colourAddition(SelectedStyle, StyleSelection.getIndex) = "Y"
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
        StyleSelection.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is showing on the line where "Next" is written

Comment: Your array _colourAddition_ contains no space for your elements. It is declared and initialized at the global level when the two variables (_NoOfStyles, NoOfColours_) have zero value. See the statement [ReDim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement)

Comment: Only `Public colourAddition(,) As String` is correct, forces you to not forget to create the array when you know how large it should be.  Not using ChkdItm in the For-Each loop is also pretty unlikely to be correct.

Comment: hi hans please give me an example of what to do

Comment: Hi Steve Your solution worked but now I am encountering another problem. When I declare the value Y to the particular indeed, it does not get saved. When I use a message box to display the value at that particular index, it is displaying a blank message. Please help

Comment: @ChekM8 When you want to respond to someone who has commented use the @ sign before their name. Then they will receive an alert in their inbox. Have you tried `ReDim Preserve`? Read a bit further on the link Steve provided.